# React style update by state change doesn't update

Tags: reactjs, styles, state, react-state

I have a simple react element that should update its style depending on screen size. For some reason it doesn't update.

Here is the code:

```
export class DashboardHContainer extends Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {middleStyle: {display: "flex"}};
}

componentDidMount(){
    var my = this;
    window.addEventListener("resize", function(){
        if(window.innerWidth < 600){
            console.log("AAA");
            my.setState({middleStyle: {display: "none"}});
        }
        console.log(my.state.middleStyle);
    });
}

render(){
    return (
        <div className="HeaderContainer">
            <HeaderLeft/>
            <DashboardHMiddle style={this.state.middleStyle}/>
            <HeaderRight/>
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

The state itself gets updated fine, in the logs it shows that the value has been updated. But for some reason the style doesn't change and the element doesn't disappear upon resize.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem: a custom React component doesn't accept the default props, so I had to put `style={this.props.style}` in the `DashboardHMiddle`'s containing `div`.